# Force.com IDE V38.0 test running issue

Tags: unit-test, force.com, ide, force.com-ide

I just updated the Force.com IDE to the latest version, however, I am having issue running unit tests. When I open the "Run as configuration" dialog, I receive an error:
[image]

And when I filled in the project and switched the tab to "Test", there's no available test class/method to select.
[image]

The error looks like this:

```
ERROR [2017-04-04 14:05:30,944] (RunTestsView.java:enqueueTests:357) - Failed to enqueue tests. Tests array: 
ERROR [2017-04-04 14:05:32,617] (RunTestsView.java:runTests:263) - Unexpected error
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.salesforce.ide.apex.internal.core.ApexSourceUtils.lambda$1(ApexSourceUtils.java:302)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(Unknown Source)
at com.salesforce.ide.apex.internal.core.ApexSourceUtils.filterSourcesByType(ApexSourceUtils.java:303)
at com.salesforce.ide.apex.internal.core.ApexSourceUtils.filterSourcesByClass(ApexSourceUtils.java:252)
at com.salesforce.ide.apex.internal.core.ApexSourceUtils.findTestClassesInProject(ApexSourceUtils.java:70)
at com.salesforce.ide.ui.views.runtest.RunTestsView.findTestClasses(RunTestsView.java:894)
at com.salesforce.ide.ui.views.runtest.RunTestsView.runTests(RunTestsView.java:232)
at com.salesforce.ide.ui.views.runtest.RunTestsLaunchConfigurationDelegate.launch(RunTestsLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:124)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:885)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:739)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1039)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1256)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

Does anybody know what is going wrong?

Comment: Try upgrading up to the latest version first, and see if it goes away. If not, you might want to report this error [here](https://github.com/forcedotcom/idecore). I'm not sure we can help you.

Comment: I am pretty sure i installed the latest version. I have reported it to github